# Controlling the Y value of an array of water drops in processing

Tags: java, arrays, processing

I made an animation where a lot of lines (water drops) fall; by clicking with the left mouse, you just slow them down. What I also want to do is controlling their Y value as thei fall: when I click with my right mouse, they will all follow it.

```java
Drop[] drops = new Drop[270]; // array 

void setup() {
     size(640, 360); // size of the window
     for (int i = 0; i < drops.length; i++) {
         drops[i] = new Drop();
    }
}

void draw() {

    background(52);

    for (int i = 0; i < drops.length; i++) {
        drops[i].fall(); 
        drops[i].show(); 
        drops[i].noGravity(); 
    }
}
```

And the Drop class:

```java
class Drop {
    float x = random(width); // posizione x di partenza
    float y = random(-180,-100); // posizione y di partenza
    float yspeed = random(2,7); // velocità random

    void fall() { 
        y += yspeed;

        if (y > height) { // riposizionamento delle gocce
            y = random(-180,-100);
        }
    }

    void noGravity(){ //
        if(mousePressed && (mouseButton == LEFT)){
            y -= yspeed*0.75;
        }

        if(mousePressed && (mouseButton == RIGHT)){
              this.y = mouseY + yspeed;
        }
    }

    void show() { // funzione per l'aspetto delle gocce
        stroke(52, 82, 235);
        line(x,y,x,y+20);
    }
}
```

The function I'm talking about is noGravity(), but when I click the right mouse,intead of following my mouse, all the drops just line up. Any simple suggestions? Thank you all!!!

Comment: I've edited your question and have removed the [tag:javascript] question tag as the question has *nothing* to do with this programming language. No sense attracting the wrong experts to this question as this can lead to it receiving down-votes and question close-votes.

Comment: I'm so sorry. I legit thought that processing and javascript are very similar programming languages by watching also youtube coding videos. my mistake

Answer (score 0):

Changing the y position when you right click isn't the same as changing the speed at which the drops moves. You probably just didn't notice.

Here, try changing the part where you catch the right click in `noGravity()` for these lines:

```
yspeed = abs(yspeed); //this is so the drops behaves normally again when you stop right clicking
if(mousePressed && (mouseButton == RIGHT)){
  if (mouseY < this.y) { //this makes the drops go toward the mouse position
    yspeed = yspeed * -1; //going up is negative speed
  }
}
```

This is kinda cool. Notice how, if you hold the right click down, when you move the mouse the drops try to follow using their own speed. I have no idea what you're doing, but I like it.

I wasn't sure about the desired result, so let me know if I misunderstood.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's exactly what i meant! I'm a student and I'm just practicing with Processing. It's also a lot of fun!